# Microstrategy Selector Value using URL API

Tags: analytics, dashboard, microstrategy

I have a dashboard which has a selector based on an attribute.

I'd like to know if its possible to access the dashboard , with a pre-fed (pre-selected) selector value , using MSTR's URL API

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in the most recent versions of MicroStrategy (I think 9.3.1 or more recent).

There is a technote that explain how to build the URL to set a selector to the default value that you prefer:

[TN46649: How to use Mobile URL API to pass hard-coded (default) selector answers to a target document in MicroStrategy Mobile 9.3.1?](http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Mobile/TN46649-How-to-use-Mobile-URL-API-to-pass-hard-coded-default/ta-p/196298)

You can also check the following link which adds few more details:

[Defaulting Element Selectors Using URL API](http://www.bryanbrandow.com/2012/07/defaulting-element-selectors-using-url-api.html)

Comment: The procedure in the second link doesn't seem to work